# Pick video file from iPhone local library

Tags: iphone, file, video, mpmediapickercontroller

I know how to pick audio file (MPMediaPickerController), but how to pick video file???

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [iPod Library Access Developer Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/iPodLibraryAccess_Guide/AboutiPodLibraryAccess/AboutiPodLibraryAccess.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008765-CH103-SW9)

> In iPhone OS 3.0, iPod library access
>   applies only to audio-based media
>   items. You cannot play video podcasts,
>   movies, or television shows from the
>   iPod library.

Answer (score 1):

For SDK version greater than 3.0,you can do it using UIImagePickerController if the video is in Photo Library. [Picking video from PhotoLibrary with UIImagePickerController in OS 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1533180/picking-video-from-photolibrary-with-uiimagepickercontroller-in-os-3-1) may help you.