# Get video from photo album & save it to image view in app

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, video, ios6

Currently I am developing an app in which I want to get photo album saved video and then show selected

video in image view & then later on send this video to Facebook. I successfully open the photo album

but now how can i save selected video in image view of app.

Comment: Your question (although for a newer version of iOS) looks very similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1533180/picking-video-from-photolibrary-with-uiimagepickercontroller-in-os-3-1?rq=1).

Comment: No, Tom Jowett I only want to save selected video from photo album to image view in my app.

Comment: Ok I might be reading it wrong. You want to:
a) pick a video from the photo roll
b) display the chosen video in a UIView of some description in your view controller
c) upload the video to Facebook

From the question I get the impression you wish to save it again after uploading to Facebook.  Is this correct?

what seems a little unclear is if you want to do anything more than this

Comment: No first I want to save it then upload it to Facebook after upload i don't want to save it in controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have used **UIImagePickerController** to open the photo album (mediaType will be **kUTTypeMovie**)

Use the below UIImagePickerController delegate to get the videoUrl and Its thumbnail

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {        

        NSURL *videoURL  = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
        UIImage *videoThumbnail = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
```

You can save the videoURL and retrieve the Video later using [ALAsset_Class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAsset_Class/Reference/Reference.html) or even you can set the url to moviePlayer. `[moviePlayer setContentURL:movieURL];`

You can use the videoThumbnail to deal with UiImages

Finally, do a **Google search** to **Share video to Facebook.**